# Active-passive xenserver bond availibility after stacked switch failure

Tags: failover, xenserver, bonding

Citrix documentation for Xenserver recommends that when physicals NICs participating in an active-passive bond, need to be connected to different switches, the switches must be stacked..
Would the bond still fail-over to any one of the NICs if one of the switches in the stack fail or becomes unavailable for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stacking is not a requirement for active-passive bonding. See https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX132559 for clarification on the stacking requirements.

If the failure causes one of the bonded links to go down, XenServer will fail-over to the secondary link and send out gratuitous ARPs to ensure the switch knows about the MACs of the VMs running on the host.

Comment: Thanks for that link.. However http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX137599 says otherwise.. See in the middle of the article please.. It applies to xenserver 6+

Comment: Well I checked it in the xenserver Advanced Network Design Guide, and that also says what you said. Stacked switches might turn out to be a SPOF if the management switch goes down..